# Creating cooldown for command

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I've seen a lot of posts that cover this but nobody does their bot how I do. I use:

```
client = discord.Client()
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
```

for my main file.
I've seen people using:

```
@bot.command
@commands.cooldown(###)
```

but I can't do that due to me using discord.client()

Anyone know a way around this, instead of changing how my bot runs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cooldown For Command On Discord Bot Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46087253/cooldown-for-command-on-discord-bot-python)

Comment: It's different, mine is more specific to my issue.

Comment: See: [Add cooldown / timer to on_message](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50294169/6779307)

Comment: Perfect, with a little bit of tweaking I got it working. Thank!!

Answer (score 0):

I also use client = discord.Client() and

```
@commands.cooldown(1,86400, commands.BucketType.user)
```

works fine for me, so I would recommend trying it. If it doesn't work, it seems like there might be a problem with something else.